# sinon stub.callsFake does not execute every time the stubbed function runs

Tags: sinon

I am trying to write some code that will track what the return values with the callback that is passed to `Array.prototype.filter`. At the moment, I have found a way to execute the callback by stubbing the filter function and then spying on the callback by hooking into the `callsFake` function.

This works well for the first filter invocation but all subsequent invocations do not toggle `callsFake` again. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

The code I am trying to test is fairly simple code that runs three different filter functions as follows:

`code-to-be-tested.js:`

```js
// items is an array of 5 simple objects

items.filter((item) => {
    console.info("inside function")
    return true;
})

console.info("after 1")

items.filter((item) => {
    console.info("inside function 2")
    return 1 + 1;
})

console.info("after 2")


const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
nums.filter((n) => {
    console.info("inside function 3")
    return n % 2 == 0
})

console.info("after 3")
```

The sinon code I have written is:

`sinon-code.js:`

```js
let callbackFunctionSpy;
const stub = sinon.stub(Array.prototype, "filter");

stub.callsFake((callbackFunction, thisArg) => {
    console.info("callsFake")
    callbackFunctionSpy = sinon.spy(callbackFunction);
    const result = stub.wrappedMethod.apply(stub.returnsThis().thisValues[0], [callbackFunctionSpy, thisArg])

    return result;
})
```

The output I expected is

```
callsFake
inside function
inside function
inside function
inside function
inside function
after 1
callsFake
inside function 2
inside function 2
inside function 2
inside function 2
inside function 2
after 2
callsFake
inside function 3
inside function 3
inside function 3
inside function 3
inside function 3
after 3
```

but I am instead getting:

```
callsFake
inside function
inside function
inside function
inside function
inside function
after 1
after 2
after 3
```

I verified the `stub.callCount` value and it is 3. When I add or remove filter functions, it changes accordingly.

I have tried using `stub.resetHistory()` and `stub.reset()` but nothing changes. Any help would be appreciated.